# CallBack never ends because of this code -> Response.Redirect("~/Handler.ashx?path=" + {Path});

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, handler

i have a Handler.ashx in my project for showing save as dialog to my users.
also i have a repeater with a link buttons inside for click and showing the upper save as dialog at last.
i put my repeater inside an update panel!
the codes of ItemCommand Of that repeater is like below :

```
   protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //The Below Line Does Not Work - Always Is Null
            //NewAddedFiles currentItem = (NewAddedFiles)e.Item.DataItem;

            HiddenField hfFilePath = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFilePath");
            HiddenField hfFileName = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileName");
            HiddenField hfFileSize = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileSize");
            HiddenField hfFileCreationDate = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileCreationDate");

            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "lbFile_Click":
                    {
                        if (Session["User_ID"] != null)
                        {
                            DataSet dsDownload = DataLayer.Download.Size_By_UserID_Today(int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()), DateTime.Now);
                            if (dsDownload.Tables["Download"].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                DataRow drDownload = dsDownload.Tables["Download"].Rows[0];

                                int SumOfFileSize4Today = int.Parse(drDownload["FileSizSum"].ToString());

                                if (SumOfFileSize4Today + int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 1073741824)//1 GB = 1024*1024*1024 bytes = 1073741824 bytes
                                //if (SumOfFileSize4Today + int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 100000)
                                {
                                    DataLayer.Download.InsertRow(
                                               int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()),
                                               DateTime.Now,
                                               hfFilePath.Value,
                                               hfFileName.Value,
                                               hfFileSize.Value,
                                               DateTime.Parse(hfFileCreationDate.Value)
                                             );
                                    Response.Redirect("~/HandlerForRepeater.ashx?path=" + hfFilePath.Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload", "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload();", true);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 1073741824)
                                //if (int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 100000)
                                {
                                    DataLayer.Download.InsertRow(
                                               int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()),
                                               DateTime.Now,
                                               hfFilePath.Value,
                                               hfFileName.Value,
                                               hfFileSize.Value,
                                               DateTime.Parse(hfFileCreationDate.Value)
                                             );
                                    Response.Redirect("~/HandlerForRepeater.ashx?path=" + hfFilePath.Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload", "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload();", true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload", "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload();", true);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

the important part of this code is :

```
 Response.Redirect("~/HandlerForRepeater.ashx?path=" + hfFilePath.Value);
```

because of this line callback never ends and when save as dialog comes up , repeater area goes to thinkink mode and is disabled!

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely familiar with UpdatePanels but I think you have pretty much answered this yourself when you say the 'callback never ends and when save as dialog comes up, repeater area goes to thinking mode and is disabled'.

What is happening is you are not returning a page response to your request but instead making a request to the server from your page which is redirecting to your handler which I am guessing is responding with a file download. The page you requested from is now stale, if you want to carry on using this page you need to return it as the response instead.

Two options you could consider are:

1. Instead or redirecting to your handler let the response continue as normal and instead register a script to make a request to your handler asyncronously passing it the file path.
2. Using jQuery call a web method asyncronously to handle this using the ajax method.

Comment: thanks for answer / option #1 failed -> same manner / the latest way is option # 2 / but is there any other way for fix this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not overly familiar with update panels so am not sure why option is not working. As long as there are no redirects I would have thought the response should have just returned as expected. If I get time I'll investigate further but hopefully someone else might turn up with an explanation.

Comment: Check this out, possibly an issue with repeaters in update panels: http://forums.asp.net/p/1029795/1410614.aspx

Comment: dear Andy Rose , so sorry -> Option #1 Works Perfect - that was my mistake - i had been changed the other else in my code - so sorry and thanks for help ... i marked ur answer as my answer